# To have multiple sub-domains or multiple separate domains?

Tags: php, vps

My client has a host of Facebook pages that have become very successful. In order to move away from big brother Facebook my client wishes to create a large dynamic site that incorporates the more successful parts of the Facebook empire.

One of my client's spin off sites has been created and is getting a lot of traffic. I'm not sure exactly how much but it hit 90 Gigs in a month as the space allocated need to be increased.

In any case my client has dreamed up a massive website with its own community looking to put the community under the one banner. However I am concerned that it will get thrashed, bottlenecks, long load time, etc.

My questions:

- Will a managed dedicated server be able to handle a potentially large amount of traffic?
- Is it going to be better to create various parts of the empire in their own separate hosting and domain (normal hosting or VPS), or is it better to have them all under the one hood (i.e. using sub-domains).
- If they were all together would it be better for SEO and easier to manage? Or if they are separate, they may be quicker but would it need some sort of Passport user system so people can log into any of the website with the same user details?
- Whats the best way to implement a Passport style user system? Do you remotely connect to databases? Or run a regular a Cron job that updates each individual user details on each domain? Maybe run CURL request to the other site given then any new data?
- Any other Pros/Cons to keeping all the section together or separating them?

Large site like Facebook manages to have everything under the one root. Then sites like eBay have separate domain names but you can use the same user login across all of them.

I'm not sure what the best option is and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: DNS does let you point different subdomains at different ip addresses and different domains at the same ip address. The decision about how many domains you have is unrelated to any issues about load.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very general question but to give some hints:

1. Measure, measure and measure again. Know what kind of parts are used heavily and which are not.
2. Fix things and go back to 1.

Really: Without knowing what takes lots of time, what is used most heavily etc. you cannot say anything usefull.

VPS or dedicated servers are not the right question. You start with: What do I have to do for the users. Then: How am I going to do that? (for example: in database, in scripts, in message queue) and then finally you see how much hardware you need.

One or multiple domains doesn't really matter. Though one exception: For static content it might be interesting if you have lots of it to use a CDN like Amazon. Read for example: http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/12/27/plentyoffish-update-6-billion-pageviews-and-32-billion-image.html where you can read some things about the possibilities with a CDN.

In general serving static content from a static domain is useful many other things don't really need that. So there you could just consider all in one domain.